# Does eating a low yeast diet help control recurrent candida albicans (vaginal thrush)?

Tags: nutrition

[About.com](http://altmedicine.about.com/od/popularhealthdiets/a/candidadiet.htm) and  others (including a  brochure from my GP) suggest eliminating all yeast products from the diet to help control candida vaginal thrush symptoms:

> Some alternative practitioners use diet to address Candida overgrowth. For example, Dr. Crook recommends people with Candida overgrowth follow certain diet guidelines:
>   [...] Avoid foods containing any type of yeast. This includes fermented foods such as bread made with yeast, cheese, tomato paste, mushrooms, and beer. Although Dr. Crook believed that people with Candida overgrowth would also be allergic to other fungi, not all practitioners believe this restriction is necessary.

Some places suggest this relates to allergy due to the sensitization by candida.

Is there any evidence that eliminating yeast products can help to control symptoms or prevent recurrence of vaginal thrush?

Comment: Note: The same link explains "This yeast syndrome, popularized by William Crook, MD, in his 1983 book, The Yeast Connection, is considered highly controversial. Most conventional doctors think this syndrome is overdiagnosed by holistic practitioners and many disagree with the validity of the diagnosis."